# How to select or sort using order by array in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, session-variables

```
$return=DB::table('products')
                ->select('products.*', 'images.address')
                ->leftJoin("images",function($join){
                            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'images.product_id');
                            $join->where('images.default','1');
                        })
                ->whereIn('products.id',session("idcompare"))
                ->get();
```

1. `session('idcompare')` has values (1,4,2)
2. When this is selected, the result set for `products.id` is in order 1,2,4
3. How to select or order by my session?

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify and ORDER BY clause, MySQL will return the results in the order they were retrieved (in this case in the order they are retrieved by is perhaps a scan or key on idcompare).

Answer (score 4):

Another way,  put this line before your get

```
->orderByRaw('FIELD(products.id,session("idcompare"))')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $arr=[];
        foreach(session("idcompare") as $i){
            foreach($return as $j) {
                if ($i == $j->id) {
                    $arr[] = $j;
                }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
```

1. Ohh this is easy